# Does the save method of JPA Repositry in springboot actually commit?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying a very basic problem using spring boot framework, in which I am using JPA Repository for some basic functionalities, where I am using save method to save the details of the person class in an in-memory database H2, but I figured out that save actually is not committing the data as I can't retrieve the details after I bounce the spring-boot application. Before bouncing and in the same session if I try to get the details of the data which was saved using the save method, I am able to retrieve those details.
PLease suggest whether save method actually commits or not?
I have tried to add a property in the application.properties so to ensure every time new records aren't created. 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
But still no luck

Entity class:->
    package com.shubhmah.springbootapp.PersonDetails;

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data 
@Entity 
public class PersonDetails
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String middleName;

    private String lastName;

    private String dateOfBirth;

    PersonDetails(){

    }

    PersonDetails(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String dateOfBirth){
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.middleName= middleName;
        this.lastName= lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth=dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Repository Class:->

```
package com.shubhmah.springbootapp.PersonDetails;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

 interface PersonDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonDetails, Long> {
}
```

The Application Class:->

```
package com.shubhmah.springbootapp.PersonDetails;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class PersonRestController {

    protected List<PersonDetails> personDetails;
    private  final PersonDetailsRepository personDetailsRepository;

    PersonRestController(PersonDetailsRepository pr){
        this.personDetailsRepository= pr;
    }
    @PostMapping("/person/savePerson")
    PersonDetails savePerson(@RequestBody PersonDetails personDetails){
        return  personDetailsRepository.save(personDetails);

    }
    @GetMapping("/person/getAllPerson")
    protected List<PersonDetails> getPersons(){
        personDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        personDetails = personDetailsRepository.findAll();
        return personDetails;
    }
    @GetMapping("/person/getSortedPerson")
    protected List<PersonDetails> getSortedDetails(@RequestParam String sort){
        return personDetailsRepository.findAll(Sort.by(sort));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save` method does not commit, it just calls `EntityManager.merge` which doesn't even do a flush. 
This means depending on the state of your entity instance it might not touch the database at all.

Handling of transactions is an orthogonal concern and in a standard Spring setup controlled by `@Transactional` annotations. 
Spring will (again in the default case) commit the transaction when the outermost annotated method returns.
This will trigger a flush of changes to the database followed by a commit.

The `save` method has such an annotation and thereby will Spring will create a transaction around it if there are no other `Transactional` annotations present.

Read more about [Springs Transaction Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction)

*Note: `save` is a method from Spring Data, not of Spring Boot*

Comment: please share any example how can I commit